# openCv and PyTorch inverser Transform not working

Tags: numpy, pytorch, opencv, python

I have a transforms class which only does:

```
        if transform is None:
            transform = transforms.Compose([
                transforms.Resize((256, 256)),
                transforms.ToTensor()
            ])
        root = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT_DIR, "data")
        super(AttributesDataset, self).__init__()
        self.data = torchvision.datasets.CelebA(
            root=root,
            split=split,
            target_type='attr',
            download=True,
            transform=transform
        )
```

From the documentation, I understand that this implies just a scale-down of values in the range 0,1 ie all pixel values shall lie between [0,1] (I have verified this as well).
I want to visualize some of the outputs coming from the model. As such, I created a simple method which does:-

```
    for img, label in dataloader:
        img.squeeze_(0)
        # permute the channels. cv2 expects image in format (h, w, c)
        unscaled_img = img.permute(1, 2, 0)
        # move images to cpu and convert to numpy as required by cv2 library
        unscaled_img = torch.round(unscaled_img * 255)
        unscaled_img = unscaled_img.to(torch.uint8)
        # unscaled_img = np.rint(unscaled_img * 255).astype(np.uint8) 
        unscaled_img = cv2.cvtColor(unscaled_img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
        cv2.imshow(unscaled_img.numpy())
```

However, all the images that are created have an unusually blue shade. For instance,

[image: A lot of blue shade appearing]

Can someone please tell me what exactly am I doing wrong here? Your help would be highly appreciated

Comment: Maybe red was replaced by blue and blue was replaced with red here `unscaled_img = cv2.cvtColor(unscaled_img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)`. How is the original picture looking alike?

Comment: Yes you are right. I checked it and commenting out the line solved the issue. Thanks

Comment: I'm glad the issue has been resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by @LajosArpad comment. The culprit was

```
unscaled_img = cv2.cvtColor(unscaled_img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
```

Removing it resulted in correct values.